# WebRTC Peer to Server instead of Peer To Peer

Tags: python, django, server, webrtc, django-channels

## WebRTC Peer to Server instead of Peer To Peer

I want to build a WebRTC Video and Voice Calling App.
However, I do not want a user to be able to connect directly to another user, as this brings unwanted security risks. So I think it makes more sense to implement the whole thing in such a way that all users (2 in this case) connect to a server, which then distributes the data and the users do not distribute it among themselves, so that, for example, the IP is publicly visible.

## I don't want that:

[image]

So even I think this is the normal way you could do it I don't want to, because, how I said there are a lot of security risks that this kind of connection brings with it.

## I want that:

[image]

I've heard that Discord, for example, does exactly what I show in the graphic (at least similarly). Can this be implemented? And if so, how? By the way, I used Python Django in the backend. I was wondering whether this could also be done with Python Django Channels. So is there an implementation in Django Channels that I can set up a WebRTC server? Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a TURN relay server and set the `RTCIceTransportPolicy` to [relay](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#rtcicetransportpolicy-enum) when creating the `RTCPeerConnection` in the browser. That will result in the media path matching your bottom diagram.

Answer (score 1):

ALL public peer-to-peer communications use a server in the middle.  Virtually every end-user computer in the world today sits behind a firewall and cannot be directly addressed from outside their network.